# How To Fix Error Automation Game Python Code

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm Trying To Use An Automation Piano Game With Python, But When I Want To Try Implementing The Code, I Get An Error
As Shown In The Attached Picture
Please Help Me To Fix This Error, I Used ** Python 3.8.4 **

```
*<!-- The Code -->*
import mss as mss
import numpy as np
from cv2 import cv2
import time
import pyautogui
import keyboard

pyautogui.PAUSE = 0.005


def take_screenshot():
    with mss.mss() as sct:
        filename = sct.shot(output="fullscreen.png")
    return filename


# take_screenshot()

def get_frame(region):
    with mss.mss() as sct:
        screen = np.array(sct.grab(region))
        screen_grayscale = cv2.cvtColor(screen, cv2.COLOR_BGR2BGRA)
        # print(screen_grayscale.shape)
        # cv2.imwrite('region.png', screen_grayscale)
    return screen_grayscale


def detect_tiles(frame):
    for x in range(frame.shape[0]):
        for y in range(frame.shape[1]):
            if frame[x, y] == 1:
                return x, y
    return None


region = {"top": 560, "left": 350, "width": 300, "height": 2}

time.sleep(3)

while True:
    if keyboard.is_pressed('q'):
        break
    start_time = time.time()
    frame = get_frame(region)
    coors = detect_tiles(frame)
    if coors:
        target_x = region['left'] + coors[1] + 1
        target_y = region['top'] + coors[0] + 1
        pyautogui.moveTo(x=target_x, y=target_y)
        pyautogui.mouseDown()
    print("%d FPS" % (1 / (time.time() - start_time)))

*<!-- end code -->*
```

my error image:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your problem seems to stem from the fact that frame[x,y] is not a single value but a list or tuple of values.  Hence, when you execute `if frame[x,y] == 1` you get an error message like `ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()`.

Depending on what you want to accomplish you can use one of the following remedies:

1. Use the .all method which will result in True if and only if all elements of frame[x]  and frame[y] equal 1.  Using the following:
    `if frame[x,y].all() == 1:`
2. Use the .any method which will result in True if and only if any frame[x] or frame[y] element equals 1. Using the following:
    `if frame[x,y].any() == 1`